# ValueError('Missing scheme in request url: %s' % self._url) when calling the spider while modifying start_url argument

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler, jupyter-notebook

I´m working with a scraper, with scrapy through the jupyter notebook .

This is the code of the scraper, saved in a python file

```
import scrapy


from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.http import HtmlResponse

class GoogleApipoweredContentScraperSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'google_apipowered_content_scraper'

    start_urls = ['https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#topics-selectors']

    def parse(self, response):
        texta = response.xpath("//text()").extract()
        texttitle = response.xpath('//title/text()').extract()
        yield {"Article_title" : texttitle, "Content_text" :texta}


</blink>
```

The scraper works just fine for starters when you call and execute it normaly like this.

```
<blink>
!scrapy runspider google_apipowered_content_scraper.py

</blink>
```

Here is the thing,  the doc.scrapy start url was just as an example to execute, I actually plan on modifying that variable when calling ( that is where the error happens, this is the code I am using:

```
!scrapy runspider google_apipowered_content_scraper.py -a "start_urls=[https://elpais.com/internacional/2019/01/23/actualidad/1548249429_996363.html]"
```

But it does not work, Here the error that produces:

```
    019-01-23 20:21:43 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.5.1 started (bot: scrapybot)
2019-01-23 20:21:43 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.2.1.0, libxml2 2.9.8, cssselect 1.0.3, parsel 1.5.1, w3lib 1.20.0, Twisted 18.9.0, Python 3.6.5 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Apr 29 2018, 16:14:56) - [GCC 7.2.0], pyOpenSSL 18.0.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.0i  14 Aug 2018), cryptography 2.4.1, Platform Linux-4.15.0-43-generic-x86_64-with-debian-buster-sid
2019-01-23 20:21:43 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings: {'SPIDER_LOADER_WARN_ONLY': True}
2019-01-23 20:21:43 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.memusage.MemoryUsage',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
2019-01-23 20:21:43 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2019-01-23 20:21:43 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2019-01-23 20:21:43 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2019-01-23 20:21:43 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2019-01-23 20:21:43 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2019-01-23 20:21:43 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6027
2019-01-23 20:21:43 [scrapy.core.engine] ERROR: Error while obtaining start requests
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/stefano/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/core/engine.py", line 127, in _next_request
    request = next(slot.start_requests)
  File "/home/stefano/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/spiders/__init__.py", line 83, in start_requests
    yield Request(url, dont_filter=True)
  File "/home/stefano/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/http/request/__init__.py", line 25, in __init__
    self._set_url(url)
  File "/home/stefano/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/http/request/__init__.py", line 62, in _set_url
    raise ValueError('Missing scheme in request url: %s' % self._url)
ValueError: Missing scheme in request url: [
2019-01-23 20:21:43 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2019-01-23 20:21:43 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 23, 19, 21, 43, 224181),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 1,
 'log_count/ERROR': 1,
 'log_count/INFO': 7,
 'memusage/max': 55255040,
 'memusage/startup': 55255040,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 23, 19, 21, 43, 219808)}
2019-01-23 20:21:43 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)

    </blink>
```

Mainly the error seems to be related to this ValueError('Missing scheme in request url: %s' % self._url)

I have tried writing the start_url when calling the argument, with brackets and without brackets [], I have also tried adding the webpages domain, with a coma after adding the url, and not adding it. In All cases I get the same error.

The code should result giving back all the text inside the url, disorganized of course, but all the text. Working on this : 'Python version 3.6.5 |Anaconda version 5.2.0,jupyter notebook 5.5.0

I´m completely new to web scraping, I have no idea how to fix this, I´m still trying though and I keep working from this side, I have seen a lot of posts but none of them aply to a case like mine, where I´m modifying the start_url variable from jupyter notebook. Most of them make the mistake of not adding [], but that is clearly not my case.  Hope it´s fun and makes the community  smarter . Thanks in advance.

Comment: why the negative votes? , what can I do to improve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I became very interested and I solved your problem)).
add this to your code:

1. In class GoogleApipoweredContentScraperSpider add:

   `my_start_page = ''`
2. Add method:

   `def start_requests(self):
           if self.my_start_page is not None and self.my_start_page != '':
               self.my_start_page = self.my_start_page.split(',')
               for url in self.my_start_page:
                   yield self.make_requests_from_url(url)
           else:
               for url in self.start_urls:
                   yield self.make_requests_from_url(url)`

TESTED !!! EVERYTHING IS WORKING!!!

```
scrapy runspider google_apipowered_content_scraper.py -a my_start_page=https://elpais.com/internacional/2019/01/23/actualidad/1548249429_996363.html,https://www.yoursitenb2.com
```

If you want to transfer one url to the start, then just remove the `split(',')` and loop. just: `self.make_requests_from_url(self.my_start_page)`

Comment: thank you for helping, My solution was in the direction of avoiding the problem directly by making the spider through beautifull soup, I´m going to try this solution and come back , thank you never theless

Comment: should I add that method replacing parse? or as an additional method? Could you please explain the nature of the problem and the solution  ( I want to  understand better web scraping with scrapy ). For example, what does this domain do in the code? ",https://www.yoursitenb2.com  "  , why that particular domain?   ,what does this part of the code do? < yield self.make_requests_from_url(url) > , an this <     else:
            for url in self.start_urls:
                yield self.make_requests_from_url(url) >.

Comment: 1. Yes, you must add this method as an additional.
2. Nature of the problem: In Python, all arguments passed through the terminal are string variables (text). And Scrapy requires an array of start_urls links as an argument for parsing. (start_urls = **[** url_1, url_2, url_3 **]**).
3. I wrote yoursitenb2.com for example only))) This means your_site_number_2.com (second link in the array)

Comment: 4. `def start_requests(self): # this method starting before parse 
        if self.my_start_page is not None and self.my_start_page != '':
            self.my_start_page = self.my_start_page.split(',')
            for url in self.my_start_page:
                yield self.make_requests_from_url(url) #make request to the site before scraping and sending callback in to parse method`
_This all provides a start if there are arguments in the terminal._

Comment: `else:
            for url in self.start_urls:
                yield self.make_requests_from_url(url)`

And this code takes the start_urls if you run the scrapie from the terminal without arguments

Comment: thank you for everything, this effectively solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

```
!scrapy runspider google_apipowered_content_scraper.py -a "start_urls=['https://elpais.com/internacional/2019/01/23/actualidad/1548249429_996363.html']"
```

try this

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, but it seems to me that you cannot do this without changing Scrapy, because the Command line arguments are always passed as strings in it.

```
def start_requests(self):
        cls = self.__class__
        if method_is_overridden(cls, Spider, 'make_requests_from_url'):
            warnings.warn(
                "Spider.make_requests_from_url method is deprecated; it "
                "won't be called in future Scrapy releases. Please "
                "override Spider.start_requests method instead (see %s.%s)." % (
                    cls.__module__, cls.__name__
                ),
            )
             for url in self.start_urls:
                yield self.make_requests_from_url(url)
        else:
            for url in self.start_urls:
                yield Request(url, dont_filter=True)
```

This is a clipping from the Scrapys code.

So that your argument would understand Scrapy, you need to add to Scrapy:

```
for url in self.start_urls:
   yield self.make_requests_from_url(url)
```

this:

```
for url in self.start_urls.strip('[]').split(','))
   yield self.make_requests_from_url(url)
```

And run Scrapy with that argument:

```
scrapy runspider google_apipowered_content_scraper.py -a start_urls=[https://elpais.com/internacional/2019/01/23/actualidad/1548249429_996363.html,https://www.another_url.com]
```

but I'm not sure that there is no more cycle for getting URLs from an array. Need to find.

And here are the crutches)))

Comment: although this option can break everything))